# Setting CartoDB tag to synonym of CARTO?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

With the [rebrand of CartoDB to CARTO](https://carto.com/blog/welcome-to-carto-builder/) we need help from a moderator or someone with +2500 reputation points to set up `carto` as synonym of `cartodb` so we keep all questions organized.

Comment: What should happen to the [tag:cartodb.js] tag?

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks for asking, as for now the library continues as cartodb.js, it may change its name but not yet :-)

Answer (score 8):

I've created a [carto](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carto) tag and made [cartodb](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cartodb) a synonym.